# CASE and TO_DATE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding CASE in Oracle.
I have a table with, say, two columns and want to create a third column based on those two.

The first column has a combination of a day and a month, stored as NUMBER, e.g. 2305 --> 23rd of May, 503 --> 5th of March etc. Those values are all valid days or NULL. The second column has a year (stored as NUMBER, NOT NULL), e.g. 2019, 2018.
I want now to make a DATE column out of the two, such that if the value in the first column is NULL, then the new column should be NULL, otherwise the concaternation of the first and second column as a DATE
.
E.g.

```
day   year       result
2305  2018   --> 23/05/2018
505   2019   --> 05/05/2019
NULL  2020   --> NULL
```

I tried:

```
CASE WHEN day IS NOT NULL THEN TO_DATE (LPAD (TO_CHAR (day || year), 8, '0'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') ELSE NULL END AS date
```

but it throws the error "ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month".

I googled and found on Stack Overflow that sometimes, the "THEN" expression in a CASE-Statement is evaluated before checking for the WHEN condition. This could be the problem as LPAD gives a result not convertible into a DATE when day is NULL. Is there a way to circumvent this? Ideally, I would like some command which tells Oracle to first check if day is NULL or not and then only evaluate the result if it is not NULL. Or is there another way for my problem?

Best regards.

Comment: The code you 've posted gets ORA-00907. If you just add `)` after `year` then it works (though that `to_char()` is redundant). The error suggests you're doing an implicit conversion, but it's hard to tell exactly where withut seeing your actual code.

Comment: @AlexPoole Look closely at the format mask being used, and then compare to the actual text data being fed into `TO_DATE`.  Actually, my answer might also be leaving out a step to format the date a certain way.

Comment: @Tim - Oracle [doesn't error on that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b54cd1afa77bdecf3ee9490d7b9b3a50) by [default](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) - which is often more of a curse than a blessing... Even with FX it's the wrong error.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Sorry, I forgot (in this question) the ")" after year. But with ")" it does not work for me. I edited now.

Comment: @user13832956 - but that works [in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b54cd1afa77bdecf3ee9490d7b9b3a50). So either your code is still different, or you have other invalid data - e.g. a day which is fewer then 3 digits.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I am positive that my days are all valid. My code is indeed much longer and I do select more columns than the ones in the question -- but could this affect this part of the query?

Comment: @user13832956 - other code shouldn't matter, Do you have rows with `day` set and `year` null, or less that 4 digits? Also which version of Oracle are you using - identifying the invalid data will be easier in some than others.

Comment: e.g. in recent versions you can use `on conversion error` to spot the bad rows; [demo db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95650b67f7617d5d59c4657a19b3461f), where bad data is reported at 9999-12-31 to highlight it. (Assuming you have no real data with that date!)

Comment: @user13832956 before jumping on to solution, you might want to fix your design first. You should ideally have a single date column instead of separate day and year columns. Life would be much simpler!!!

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Thank you -- I agree that life would be much simpler, unfortunately it is outside my power to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

Using `LPAD()`

```
select  case when day is null then null else to_char(to_date(lpad(date1, 4, 0)||year1, 'ddMMyyyy'), 'dd/MM/YYYY') as result from table;
```

Example for LPAD:

```
select to_char(to_date(lpad(date1, 4, 0)||year1, 'ddMMyyyy'), 'dd/MM/YYYY') from
(select '505' as date1, 2019 as year1 from dual
union all
select '2305' as date1, 2018 as year1 from dual);
```

Using `CASE`

```
select case when day is null then null else 
to_date((case when length(day) = 3 then '0'||ltrim(rtrim(day)) else ltrim(rtrim(day)) 
end)||ltrim(rtrim(year)), 'ddMMyyyy') end as result 
from table;
```

Example for CASE:

```
select to_date((case when length('505') = 3 then '0'||ltrim(rtrim('505')) else ltrim(rtrim('505')) end)||'2019', 'ddMMyyyy') as result from dual;
select to_date('2305'||'2019', 'ddMMyyyy') as result from dual;
```

Comment: Can I really use day = null?

Comment: My bad, use day is null. Edited the query

Comment: The `lpad` is being applied after day and year are concatenated, so 505 and 2019 will become 05052019 - which looks OK?

Comment: Yes, providing you one more query using lpad

Comment: Provided using LPAD as well as CASE

Comment: Is an "end" missing in the query?

Comment: Please use end before `as result`. Edited the query. Provided you two methods, you can use any of them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go this route, you should be first converting the `day` and `year` fields to text using `TO_CHAR`, then left padding `day` with up to one zero, and finally calling `TO_DATE` on the concatenation between these two fields:

```
SELECT
    day,
    year,
    CASE WHEN day IS NOT NULL
         THEN TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(day), 4, '0') || TO_CHAR(year), 'ddmmyyyy') END AS "date"
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

But note that your life would be *much* easier if you just kept a single proper date column to store your date information.

Comment: Regarding your note: Unfortunately this is not my choice -- the value is stored in a column where there are also proper NUMBERs (and extracted from there).

Comment: I receive the same error with your statement as I received before (in my code, I have selected many more columns then only those three -- could this somehow be a problem?).

Comment: Then my guess is that you have other data, not actually included in your question, which is breaking the code in my answer.  My answer is valid for the data you did show us.

Comment: Hm, could you explain what kind of data could it be that breaks the code? Do you mean data in the day and year column or something else?

Comment: @user13832956 - a day value with two digits e.g. 12 so when padded that becomes 0012, which gives DD 00, which is illegal. Or 3106 would be illegal DD for June. That's why you should use the proper date data type, to avoid this sort of bad data.

Comment: @AlexPoole Not really.  The sample data has one data point with a single digit day, and another with a two digit day.  Both are working.  My calls to `LPAD` specify the width.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I am positive that my dates are all valid. Unfortunately I don't have the power to use the proper data type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I was responding to "what kind of data", following on from your "other data". I agree the samples in the question are fine - but they are with the OP's original code too.